# Deleted picture still visible in gallery

Tags: android, libgdx, gallery

I have a small problem here.

In my application I let the user select a picture from the gallery. I save the path to it before doing anything else.
When the user picks the picture he wants, I want it to be copied in a other folder, and then deleted from the original one.

Well, it kiiinda works. The original picture is deleted, and a copy appears in the other folder.
Buuut. It's still there. **The deleted picture can still be seen in the gallery, and the copy can't be seen.** When I call `Gdx.files.absolute(originalPath).exists()` it returns false, and `Gdx.files.external(copyPath).exists()` it returns true, and I can work with the copy of the picture with no problem.

It looks like the gallery is not updated.

I use this to delete and copy a picture :

```
public void MoveToCustomFolder() {
    if (DoesOriginalPathExist()) {
        if (!DoesCopyExist()) {
            System.out.println("Copying");
            Gdx.files.external("/CustomFolder/" + fileName).write(Gdx.files.absolute(filePath).read(), true);
        }
        System.out.println("Deleting");
        Gdx.files.absolute(filePath).delete();
    }
}
```

`filePath` being the absolutePath of the original picture in the gallery and `fileName` the name of the file ("picture.jpg")

I found something during my research. When clear the data of the media storage application, after little time the correct gallery shows up, with no deleted pictures and with copies where they belong.

Also, I do have the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

Do you guys know what's wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution.

I had to update the Gallery with this function :

```
public void UpdateGallery(String filePath) {
    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath))));
}
```