# Change image, how can I reload the mediastore?

Tags: android

I change a content from an image. Path and filename are the same. If I reload the image for the ImageView

```
imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse("pathOfTheImage"));
```

I only see the old Image.

I try to reload the image in the mediastore after changing the image content:

```
            File file = new File(targetPath, nameImage);
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
            try {
                fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOutputStream);
                fileOutputStream.flush();
                fileOutputStream.close();
                originalBitmap.recycle();
                scaledBitmap.recycle();
            } catch(Exception e){}

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,file.getAbsolutePath());
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE,"image/png");
            context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,values);
```

What I do wrong? I only see the old image. After restart the app, ImageView displays the new image.

Comment: I had a similar issue a few years ago, which I found a solution to. Maybe it'll help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/26742950/4186837

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it doesnt work by me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out to myself. I use a simpleAdapter to put the image in a ListView. I need to renew the adapter everytime if I update my ListView.

```
simpleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

on the end doesnt work in my case.

I didnt need

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,file.getAbsolutePath());
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE,"image/png");
            context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,values);
```